# Query mysql return an error Incorrect key file for table

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I have a site in joomla I hosts locally on an Ubuntu server. When a query is executed by mysql, I get the following error:

**Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_6ef4_1.MYI';**

Here is my configuration:

PHP exécuté surLinux 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64
Version de la base de données5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1Interclassement de la base de donnéesutf8_general_ci

Version de PHP5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11

Serveur webApache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

Serveur web pour interface PHPapache2handler

Version de JoomlaJoomla! 3.3.1 Stable [ Ember ] 11-June-2014 13:30 GMT
Version de la plateforme Joomla!Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ] 24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT

NavigateurMozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Version de Mysql 5.5.24

thank you...

Answer (score 0):

According to google - this error is often related to not enough disk space left on the drive your temporary directory is located on.
You can check it with `df -h`